# Avoid repeating the same styling with kable_styling

Tags: r, r-markdown, kable, kableextra

Using Rmarkdown and kable, I need to repeat several tables with the same formatting but with different datasets.

For example, in the following two chunks, what is changing is the DF, the variable used to sort and the caption.

Is there any way to avoid repeating 90% of the same code for each chunk?

```
kable(Crib1 %>% arrange(-Z1) %>%
  select(Ranking = TYP, SID, Statement, FA1:FA3), longtable = TRUE, booktabs = TRUE, caption = "Crib Sheet - Factor 1") %>% 
  collapse_rows(1, latex_hline = "major", valign = "top") %>%
  kable_styling(full_width = FALSE, latex_options = c("hold_position", "condensed", "repeat_header"), font_size = 9) %>%
    column_spec(1, bold=TRUE) %>%
    column_spec(3, width = "18em", italic = TRUE) %>%
    column_spec(4, bold = TRUE)
```

```
kable(Crib2 %>% arrange(-Z2) %>%
  select(Ranking = TYP, SID, Statement, FA1:FA3), longtable = TRUE, booktabs = TRUE, caption = "Crib Sheet - Factor 2") %>% 
  collapse_rows(1, latex_hline = "major", valign = "top") %>%
  kable_styling(full_width = FALSE, latex_options = c("hold_position", "condensed", "repeat_header"), font_size = 9) %>%
    column_spec(1, bold=TRUE) %>%
    column_spec(3, width = "18em", italic = TRUE) %>%
    column_spec(4, bold = TRUE)
```

I am trying to build a function

```
createKableCrib <- function(factor){
  Crib <- rlang::sym(paste("Crib", factor, sep=""))
  Z <- rlang::sym(paste("Z", factor, sep=""))
  cap <- paste("Crib Sheet - Factor", factor, sep=" ")

kable(!!Crib %>% arrange(!!(-Z)) %>%
        select(Ranking = TYP, SID, Statement, FA1:FA3), 
      longtable = TRUE, booktabs = TRUE, caption = cap) %>% 
  collapse_rows(1, latex_hline = "major", valign = "top") %>%
  kable_styling(full_width = FALSE, latex_options = c("hold_position", "condensed", "repeat_header"), font_size = 9) %>%
  column_spec(1, bold=TRUE) %>%
  column_spec(3, width = "18em", italic = TRUE) %>%
  column_spec(4, bold = TRUE)
}

createKableCrib("1")
```

But I get the following error:

```
Error in UseMethod("arrange_") : 
  no applicable method for 'arrange_' applied to an object of class "name"
```

Best,

Damien

Comment: Make it a function?

Comment: I am trying to do that. I will edit the post to show the function I am trying to build and the problem it raises..

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you may have gotten there already, but here is an example that seems to work with the use of Curly-Curly instead of the original Bang-Bang (https://www.brodrigues.co/blog/2019-06-20-tidy_eval_saga/).

Didn't have your data, but tried with `mtcars` and `iris`. If your columns are the same you could add the `select` statement after `arrange`.

```
library(dplyr)
library(knitr)
library(kableExtra)

create_kable <- function(data, column, title) {
  kable({{data}} %>% 
          arrange({{column}}),
        longtable = TRUE, booktabs = TRUE, caption = title) %>% 
  collapse_rows(1, latex_hline = "major", valign = "top") %>%
  kable_styling(full_width = FALSE, latex_options = c("hold_position", "condensed", "repeat_header"), font_size = 9) %>%
    column_spec(1, bold=TRUE) %>%
    column_spec(3, width = "18em", italic = TRUE) %>%
    column_spec(4, bold = TRUE)
}

create_kable(mtcars, mpg, "Crib Sheet - Factor 1")
create_kable(iris, Sepal.Length, "Crib Sheet - Factor 2")
```

Comment: This looks tidier.  Thank you for the link.

Comment: Exploring further, I also found this page https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/articles/programming.html  very useful.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I found so far.
Not completely satisfactory, as I wanted to be able to create the df name within the function, but I keep on getting errors.

```
createKableCrib <- function(df, factor){
  Z <- paste("Z", factor, sep="")
  cap <- paste("Crib Sheet - Factor", factor, sep=" ")
 
  kable(df  %>%  arrange_at(.vars=desc(Z)) %>%
        select(Ranking = TYP, SID, Statement, FA1:FA3), 
      longtable = TRUE, booktabs = TRUE, caption = cap) %>% 
  collapse_rows(1, latex_hline = "major", valign = "top") %>%
  kable_styling(full_width = FALSE, latex_options = c("hold_position", "condensed", "repeat_header"), font_size = 9) %>%
  column_spec(1, bold=TRUE) %>%
  column_spec(3, width = "18em", italic = TRUE) %>%
  column_spec(4, bold = TRUE)
}

createKableCrib(Crib1, "1")
```